# Cloudwatch Agent config file metric - additional EBS volume disks/partition mounts not showing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

For the config file, I have resources set to *

```
            "disk": {
            "measurement": [
                "used_percent",
                "free",
                "total",
                "used",
                "inodes_free"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
```

I only see the OS disk volume but i do not see my 2nd volume /dev/sdf which stores all the data.
Is there something missing the config file or some other configuration?
If I do an lsblk on the VM, it does list all volumes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a permission issue on the user.